# Use Function Without Calling Module

Tags: python, import, module

I am using Canopy with the Jupyter notebook. I was wondering if there was a way to use function from a module without having to call the module. For example if I have

```
import numpy as np
print np.sin(2)
```

I would want to be able to just type

```
print sin(2)
```

The first thing that comes to mind is to add the numpy functions into whatever function library that Python is using. But I was wondering if this is feasible and, if so, how I could go about doing it. Note that I want to import all functions, not just a select few.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import specific objects from a module. Try:

```
from numpy import sin

print sin(2)
```

To import *all* objects from a module into the global namespace you can use `import *`.

```
from numpy import *
print sin(2)
```

But this is *not* recommended because you can easily end up with name clashes, e.g. if two modules define a function named `sin` which version of `sin` should be called?

```
>>> import math
>>> import numpy
>>> math.sin
<built-in function sin>
>>> numpy.sin
<ufunc 'sin'>

>>> from math import *
>>> sin
<built-in function sin>
>>> from numpy import *
>>> sin
<ufunc 'sin'>
```

You can see here that the second import from `numpy` replaced `sin` in the global namespace.

For this reason it is best to import the specific objects that you need if there are only a few, otherwise just import the module and use the module name as a prefix (as per your first example). In my example if you wanted to use both `math.sin` and `nump.sin` you would either need to import the modules only and prefix using the module name, or import the functions and rename them like this:

```
from numpy import sin as np_sin
from math import sin
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from numpy import sin
print sin(2)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html  read this in details

Comment: I was hoping to be able to import all functions, not just a few.

Comment: @T-ray just read above link you will get your answer
from numpy import *